# Thermostat wiring does not provide +24V AC

Tags: thermostat, transformer

A tenant indicated a heat pump failure and that the thermostat display seemed to have been turned off / disconnected. Thermostat was removed, exposing the thermostat wires.  The Red and Blue did not read anywhere near 24V AC ( reading < 1V).

What is the next step to troubleshoot root cause?

Any reference to videos / weblinks are appreciated.

Comment: I would check the input and output voltage of the transformer.  That should tell if transformer shot or wires to thermostat are broken or problem is inside of heat pump control.

Comment: Is the system turned on?  Might be worth checking.

Comment: Make sure there are no tripped breakers, If you're comfortable doing it, you may need to get into the air handler and check the transformer there. Transformers don't fail very often, but it might have.

Comment: Red and blue aren't necessarily R and C. Heat pump wiring isn't similar to normal furnace+A/C wiring, and they're probably using blue for something that isn't C.   You have to look at the furnace end and check the docs.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson You nailed it.  Post your comment as an answer to receive credit.  The problem is photographed at https://i.stack.imgur.com/l14d8.jpg

Comment: @gatorback post your pic as your answer. The answer to "how to troubleshoot" is open it up and look for melted wiring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure there are no tripped breakers, If you're comfortable doing it, you may need to get into the air handler and check the transformer there. Transformers don't fail very often, but it might have.

## The OP indicated:  connection failure

The wirenut overheated and failed resulting in a disconnected power cable.

[image]

Comment: Wow, I would think the tenant would **smell** that.

Answer (score 2):

Turn the power off, then the wire connection you show is burnt, you need to cut the wires back until you get Clean copper on each one then reattach. That black springy thing is the inside of the melted blue wire nut. At that point turn the power on and you should be ready to go.